# How to constrain a TypeScript interface to have only string property values?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function X that accepts `Record<string, string>`:

```
function X(arg:Record<string, string>) {
 ...
}
```

I want to define a function Y that is generic in T that calls X:

```
function Y<T>(arg:T) {
 ...
 X(arg)
 ...
}
```

I want to instantiate T with interfaces that have string properties like:

```
interface UserInfo {
 name: string;
 email: string;
}

Y<UserInfo>({ name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@thewatch.org' });
```

But I cannot define `Y` because `T` is not constrained to `Record<string, string>`. If I write:

```
function Y<T extends Record<string, string>>(arg:T) {
 ...
 X(arg)
 ...
}
```

Then I cannot call Y with `UserInfo`.

How do I define Y?

Thank you!

Comment: You're running into [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbQZdN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you so much, @jcalz! That's the solution!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; it might be a few hours from now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the situation reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).  The type `Record<string, string>` is equivalent to `{[k: string]: string}`, a type with a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

TypeScript will give anonymous [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) (like the type `{name: string, email: string}`) [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) to allow you to assign them to types with index signatures, as long as the known properties don't conflict.  But it does *not* give implicit index signatures to structurally equivalent [`interface` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).  This is one of the few places where you can observe a difference in behavior between interfaces and anonymous object types (or [`type` aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) of such types).

[The reasoning](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024) given in microsoft/TypeScript#15300 is that it is "safer" to allow implicit index signature for type aliases of anonymous object types than it is to do so for interfaces, because you can [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) new members into existing interfaces while you cannot do so for anonymous object types.  I'm [not really sure I understand](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-1187723714) the motiviation behing this reasoning... but for now, anyway, that's just how TypeScript works.

---

The fix here for your example code, which is already [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) is to replace the index signature [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T extends Record<string, string>` with a [recursive constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) `T extends Record<keyof T, string>`.  We can't be sure that `T` has an index signature, but we *can* be sure that it has its own keys:

```
function Y<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(arg: T) { 
    X(arg) // this still works
}
```

And the implementation works because the generic type parameter `T` is, luckily, allowed to have an implicit index signature when we call `X()`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
interface UserInfo {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

Y<UserInfo>({ name: 'Jon', email: 'jon@thewatch.org' }); // okay
```

Looks good.  Now there's no error, because `UserInfo` is indeed assignable to `Record<keyof UserInfo, string>`, a.k.a. `{name: string, email: string}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADQBQEMBOBzAXIgJQFMI5MATAHgGcpMYxsAaRW+xgPgEpEBvRAL4AoEaEiwEiAJqUAKoiIAPKETDlqhEmSoBrIgE84wRLJZsG2Dhww58snryGJnKG9i5DhQhiszB0EESIAKrURJgAkmDAcHxOLmDoALZE+OaMANzxzkRJ6DAANml0FlleMqHhUTHW-Ikp+ADkAFIIjSy5+UWIjQBWCAACUAAWRADu6FAQwwB0ZNiNglxZQkA)