# How can this function taking object of types be typed in TS?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I have a function that accepts an object of keys and each value has a type such that *for each one* the type of one of its fields determine the type for the other field. Code:

```
// We have this Alpha type and echo function...

type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends unknown ? 0 : never]

interface Alpha<Foo extends string> {
  foo: Foo
  bar: `Depends on ${NoInfer<Foo>}`
}

declare const echo: <T extends string>(x: Alpha<T>) => void

echo({ foo: 'beta', bar: 'Depends on beta'})

// @ts-expect-error Trailing 2 is wrong
echo({ foo: 'beta', bar: 'Depends on beta 2'})

// Now we want a function (bravo) that takes a keyed index of Alphas...

declare const bravo: <T extends { [k: string]: Alpha<string> }>(xs: T) => void

bravo({
  one:  { foo: `1`,  bar: `Depends on 1` },
  // @ts-expect-error 1 !== 1x           <-- fails
  oneX: { foo: `1x`, bar: `Depends on 1` },
  two:  { foo: `2`,  bar: `Depends on 2` },
  // @ts-expect-error 2 !== 2x           <-- fails
  twoX: { foo: `2x`, bar: `Depends on 2` },
})

// how could this work?
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFNQCwQwG7QC4wJYGdQEEA2AHeUZAT32jgDsATUSAYxgHtQAzAV0vuTScoDpBAKCGlyoAHJMAkpVaQATgB4AKgD5QAXlABtFQF09dAB7JINLJwDWlJgHdKoAPygADKABcoSpCQL9ImiUZgqscPTQeIRwSgBiTCyQpubUWBjICkEA5hoA3kKgbAle8UwFoABGcApeAAYAIpDkFqB8oAAkuVKy8sqlagC+tUIDItQMuNXQ9HzpdIxMXqomZi3pmZQ5ABTGXlHwqmoAlFoaCExo1CIMzFu5RYugAOQVkMhwTwA0ldVeT43NVKtRyvd5PAZHEQgUAAAWQGAAtElyNwkQoFEwFKAVAo4GhcNlQAAmUCYUB2DGbIQ3Jh3B5-UEfb5VGrPAEpLBtRnE8GQoTQqR2cnQOxUZCgOBsTjcXiOLYVXHnE6oODi95WSBYSUakiQWhBcbGVqsHAEeAYQT8MYTKagGaUOYKxCPZZJVZA+46KxedbZfR7M0xX2bDQDNQ7DBeFQnTRnC5XIRO853cp8SBeUD3VjFUC1ACMtW+P1ZDSaHOBoALoAGn3K0LhiORDGQaIxWLzoAAhJptHnjKmfAANLxZnP54yF4t1dktNpVmvlZB2R6Z+m5omTqe5mdAtob6u1wr1+FI4woluKNvErs94lG0CL5fD1fZx61IkT5m-bdl2eOfcLhCUJgMwQozOwuC0KgZLLgoVhOEAA)

As you can see from the "fails" comments I can make Alpha work initially but in the more complex object of Alphas I fail. Can you help me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL83Am) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah keyof against itself interesting! Yeah that works thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this so that `T` is an object type whose properties are the `string`s you pass as type arguments to `Alpha`, and then make `xs` a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `T`, like this:

```
declare const bravo: <T extends { [K in keyof T]: string }>(
  xs: { [K in keyof T]: Alpha<T[K]> }
) => void
```

Note that the recursive [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `{ [K in keyof T]: string }` is used to guarantee that every property of `T` is `string` without using the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) `{ [k: string]: string }` which would reject [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) types without index signatures (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) and [How to constrain a TypeScript interface to have only string property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73954300/2887218) for more info).

Anyway, because the type of `xs` is a *homomorphic* mapped type (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)), then the compiler can infer `T` from it when you call the function (this used to be [documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) but the new handbook doesn't seem to mention it ‍♂️).  Let's test it out:

```
bravo({
  one: { foo: `1`, bar: `Depends on 1` },  // okay
  oneX: { foo: `1x`, bar: `Depends on 1` }, // error
  // --------------> ~~~
  // Type '"Depends on 1"' is not assignable to type '"Depends on 1x"'
  two: { foo: `2`, bar: `Depends on 2` }, // okay
  twoX: { foo: `2x`, bar: `Depends on 2` }, // error
  // --------------> ~~~
  // Type '"Depends on 2"' is not assignable to type '"Depends on 2x"'
})
```

Looks good.  If you hover over that function call in an IntelliSense-enabled IDE you'll get the Quick Info

```
/* const bravo: <{
    one: "1";
    oneX: "1x";
    two: "2";
    twoX: "2x";
}>(xs: {
    one: Alpha<"1">;
    oneX: Alpha<"1x">;
    two: Alpha<"2">;
    twoX: Alpha<"2x">;
}) => void */
```

showing that `T` is inferred as `{one: "1", oneX: "1x", two: "2", twoX: "2x"}`, and therefore `xs`'s type is checked against `{one: Alpha<"1">, oneX: Alpha<"1x">, two: Alpha<"2">, twoX: Alpha<"2x">}`, which succeeds for the `one` and `two` properties but fails for the `oneX` and `twoX` properties, giving you exactly the errors you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXigG1sBdUqCAD2AiQBMBnKAVyQGsk4B3JKAPxQADFABcUJBABuGMgCh5ASyR10KAIYBjaAEEANmAAWGzADE4cKrXrMoTYOhUBzfAG95UKCksSLcTygAIw10CQADABEISEYWOH4AEjd4ZDQsf1wAX3D5LMUGCC19UOgtBIcqLSM4CRxrOjj7RxdcAApqCQNjUzwASkJ8aTglBkUimra3b18oAHIgiGANOYAaYNCJOejYuwTgpZWoLL75Cbgpmdr5xeW1jbD5ndt4-luNKAAmOePT+ULiqUoOUkJUgugNMM6tgGi8oNNiABpKAqKAcCAgOAoKDkCQOJxIZzHdqBahMCQI5Go9GY7G4qDdEw4JFkfD5AYEIYjMbycGQi4eLwJCAUq4RACM4XWIUeURicP2kuO6ygAHpVVA4BwNCBAsKABqinzXcLi6hSh4RZ5NRXhZVqjUYdBwdCBdVQAC0Xu9Pp9+AAfoG3RrsOBoHMAETWvb8cURn5KFjcYBQDRMJhKZxIDRBfTQYBWUCQeZR+U22PUeOBYA8a7TY0RT4WmVWssxr52rLrd1anXV2uG+FiqDhT7m6WbEfR14d+3up0u4Oe30rr0BoNed2h4uR6ea-ifeMopNwFNpjNZnN5qAFm9hkt7-ZjqsnRSqgBUwIqKb5UKgmEFLx9xFKAIzjABuQIhSkQcwMrSCgJvWsJAjQ8EKAms4Fg59IKydoyQpKDgK6QwmTAiNcHQ6CIEHRlTDgiiqKQ646MwVDGKIzDaNI+jn0ovIOS5UYoHfVUgA)

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to extend my question to include the goal of having the function return whatever type was finally inferred. Can I update this question or should it be a new question?

Comment: I gave it a small update at the bottom with a playground link of a failed attempt to return he inferred type.

Comment:  I don't know how to deal with questions whose scopes change after I've answered them. I don't quite understand what your issue is (something is presumably unacceptable about returning `typeof xs` but I don't get what it is, or what "inferred type" you're talking about) and this isn't an appropriate place to discuss it, unfortunately.  I'd suggest you open a new question about it.

Comment: I posted a focused and hopefully clear question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945737/how-can-an-inferred-parameter-type-be-referenced-in-return-type-position.